# How to forward output of split to sftp?

Tags: bash, tar, sftp, split

I have a server that is running out of disk space. I want to move some TB sized directories into a long term archive. This is a tape robot with preferred file size of 16GB. Therefore I want to split the tar archive into 16GB parts.

`tar -czpv mydir | split -d - a 4 -b $SplitBlockSize - mydir.gz.tar`

The access to LT archive server is via `sftp`.
Is it possible to forward the output of `split` to `sftp` without storing it locally?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, you can use `sshfs`. Assuming you already have `sftp` properly configured in the direction you would like to send these files, you can map a local directory to your remote server with the following.

```
$ mkdir remote
$ sshfs user@server:/path/to/dir remote
```

Then you can adjust your command to write the split files to the mapped directory.

```
$ tar -czpv mydir | split -d -a 4 -b $SplitBlockSize - remote/mydir.gz.tar
```

In your case, I think a better solution would be to use the `--filter` option with `split`. From the `man` page of `split` -

```
--filter=COMMAND
       write to shell COMMAND; file name is $FILE
```

So doing

```
$ tar -czpv mydir | split -d -a 4 -b $SplitBlockSize --filter 'ssh user@remote "cat >$FILE"' - mydir.gz.tar
```

will write the files directly over `ssh` to your remote server. I'd suggest you set up public key authentication if you haven't already, otherwise you'll have to enter your password for each file you transfer. Which would be 64 times per TB in your case. If you expect this transfer to take a very long time, consider using `nohup` to reduce the chance of having to start over again.

Comment: Thank You very much, both approaches work! One small question: how can I change to the desired directory on the REMOTE before I write?
I have tried:

`... --filter 'ssh user@remote "cd $backupDir && cat >$FILE"' - mydir.gz.tar `

Does the variable `$backupDir` to be defined on the remote?

Comment: The first problem with what you have written is that `$backupDir` is in double quotes, so it will be replaced with whatever your local `$backupDir` variable is set to BEFORE the command is sent to remote, which I suspect is nothing. Rather than `cd` to the proper dir using a variable, just write out the directory in the command. If you really want to use a variable set on the remote machine, its complicated. When you execute `ssh` commands remotely, your `.bashrc` and `/etc/profile` aren't sourced because it is not a login shell.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/216202/why-does-an-ssh-remote-command-get-fewer-environment-variables-then-when-run-man) thread should point you in the right direction.